# Getting crash while deleting mesage?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, lg-optimus-one, force-close

I am using LG P500 Optimus one, recently upgraded to Gingerbread.  Sometimes when i read any messages and delete the same, Messaging service crashes with a Force Close error, how to rectify this problem.

Comment: You are talking about text messages (SMS), right?

Comment: yes, text message

Comment: Have you tried something other than the default SMS application - like Handcent?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you as end-user could really fix the underlying problem. That's why it's always a good idea to send those bug reports that are (sometimes) shown after a force close occurs.

**But what you could try is to delete the application data, *but this will eventually result in losing all your messages.* Go to the Preferences -> Manage Applications -> Choose the Application -> Delete application data**

Comment: No, I am using the default messaging application in the mobile, also I have tried the messaging gadget

In the application, everytime I delete a message in that I see only the progress bar rotating 

Message doesn’t appear.

 

While deleting the message directly from message center I get this error. 

“Sorry! The application Messaging (process com.android.mms) has stopped unexpectedly. Please 

Try again.” (Force close)

Answer (score -1):

Turn off the confirm before delete option. Worked on my Sony Z1.